# Bar and Line Subplot with shared y-axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to output a line chart and bar chart in horizontal sub-plot and shared y-axis but I can only output 1 but not both at the same time.

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf  

df = yf.download('SPY',period='1y')[['Adj Close','Volume']] 

df['Bin'] = pd.cut(df['Adj Close'],bins=[200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400]) 
df_a = df.groupby('Bin')['Volume'].size().reset_index()
df_a['left'] =  df_a['Bin'].apply(lambda x: x.left)
df_a.set_index('left',inplace=True) 


fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
df['Adj Close'].plot(ax=axes[0],kind='line') ## line 1 
df_a['Volume'].plot(ax=axes[1],kind='barh') ## line 2
```

1. How can I make both plots (shared y-axis) appear together ? (first picture is when I only had line 1, second picture is when I had both line 1 and 2)
2. How can I make the line plot have a longer x-axis

I tried removing the 'sharey=True' which outputs both graphs, but the y-axis is miss aligned.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Matploblib allows creating twin axes, for both the X and Y axes, using respectively the [Axes.twinx](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) and [Axes.twiny](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny.html) methods.

Using the following code, both graphs are plotted on the same plot.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

volume_ax = ax.twiny()
adj_close_ax = ax.twinx()

df['Adj Close'].plot(ax=adj_close_ax,kind='line') ## line 1 
df_a['Volume'].plot(ax=volume_ax,kind='barh', color='lightblue') ## line 2
```

[image: Twin Y-Axis]

Comment: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I am trying to output 2 graphs as subplots not one combined graph. The issue I am facing is that if I insert ' Sharey=True' the line plot dont appear but if I remove 'Sharey=True', the y-axis is not aligned

Answer (score 0):

`df.plot(kind='barh')` actually plots the bars against the range index, i.e. `range(len(df))` and relabel the axis ticks. You can use `plt.barh` instead:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
df['Adj Close'].plot(ax=axes[0],kind='line') ## line 1 

# same height with bin width
axes[1].barh(df_a.index, df_a['Volume'], height=25) ## line 2
```

Output:

[image]